# Getting single UserDTO from get in JPA with parameter leads to ConverterNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I want to get a User in an H2 database with JPA, But when I call my method I get a `ConverterNotFoundException`. How can I get a single User based on the String (Email) I pass in the parameters on get?

My controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/{email}")
    public UserDTO getUser(@PathVariable String email) {
        return userService.getByEmail(email);
    }
```

My UserService (the get on ID works):

```
 public UserDTO get(final Long id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id)
                .map(user -> mapToDTO(user, new UserDTO()))
                .orElseThrow(CustomNotFoundException::new);
    }

    public UserDTO getByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }
```

My UserRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    // add custom queries here
    
    // tried this one but same problem
    @Query("select r from User r where r.email = :email")
    UserDTO findOneByMail(@Param("email") String searchTerm);

    UserDTO findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Comment: Your query should return a `User` object and parse to `UserDTO` into the service. (I'm assuming DTO is not an entity)

Answer (score 1):

The following method in your repository will return an object of data-type `User` and doesn't know how to automatically convert it to `UserDTO`:

```java
@Query("select r from User r where r.email = :email")
    UserDTO findOneByMail(@Param("email") String searchTerm);
```

Instead, you need to change your repository to the following:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    // add custom queries here
    
    // tried this one but same problem
    @Query("select r from User r where r.email = :email")
    User findOneByMail(@Param("email") String searchTerm);

    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

and you can change your service function to the following:

```java
public UserDTO getByEmail(String email) {
        return convertToDTO(userRepository.findByEmail(email));
    }

private UserDTO convertToDTO(User user) {
        UserDTO userDto = new UserDTO();
        userDto.setName(user.getName());
        // write this for all attributes that you need in UserDTO

        return userDto;
}
```

The repository is your connection to the database. It is only storing the data-type `User` and that is what it can return. All the business logic to convert that data to a `UserDTO` has to be done in your service layer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your repository extends from a `User` object but your query is trying to parse to a `UserDTO` object. This is why you have the exception, because you have not implemented a way to parse `User` to `UserDTO`.

Here, there are two option.

- First option: Simply extends your repository from `<UserDTO, Long>`.

I assume this is not a real solution because a `DTO` not should be an entity.

- Second option: Implement the parsing from `User` to `UserDTO`.

You can do in this way:

```java
public UserDTO getByEmail(String email) {
    return new UserDTO(userRepository.findByEmail(email));
}
```

And your class `UserDTO.java`

```
public UserDTO(User user){
    name = user.getName()
    ...
}
```

There are more ways (in the end is create a new object using other object attributes), but I use this to create the the `DTOs` objects.